# I want to simplify things in my Java program

Tags: java, swing, awt

I made a game using NetBeans design tool, called WordHunt. It looks like this:

[image]

I need to make a class that will apply a mouseover effect to those 16 labels I have. This is the code that changes the icon B when enter the mouse:

```
private void b1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                
        b1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ip/imag/" +B+ ".png")));

    }
```

I had applied a default icon to the label.
After making that class, instead of writing:

`b1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ip/imag/" +B+ ".png")));`

to write className(**b1** ,**B**);
For the next label, the same thing
className(**b2** ,**C**);

Observation: b1 is a label and I have all letters icon in .png format from A to Z.

Can anybody give me an idea of how I can do that?

Comment: You should not load your images (icons) every time you hover. preload them on startup of your application. This simplifies a lot.

Comment: Looks nice, you might give JavaFX a try; though JavaFX is not production quality (sellable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this: (rough draft)

```
// for storage so we don't load it for each mouse-over
HashMap<String, ImageIcon> images = new HashMap<String, ImageIcon>();

void setIcon(JLabel button, String image)
{
  if (images.containsKey(image))
    return images.get(image);
  else
  {
    String path = "/ip/imag/" + image + ".png";
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
    images.put(image, icon);
    return icon;
  }
}
```

And then:

```
setIcon(b1, "B");
```

But you should probably consider using buttons so you can use [`setRolloverIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) rather than `MouseEntered`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem it's not setting the mouseover effect. I need to make a function that will be used like: className(b1 ,B); and do the same thing for the other labels: className(b2 ,C); and so on.

Comment: @DanielPatilea Well, you could just rename the above function to `className`. If this doesn't solve your problem, I'm afraid I'm not really sure what you want. Note that if it has to be `className(b1, B);`, you can just have a `String B = "B";` and the function will look the same. Though if you don't want a variable for each letter, you're stuck with using `"B"`, not `B`.

Comment: I used this code: `HashMap<String, ImageIcon> images = new HashMap<String, ImageIcon>();
    ImageIcon setIcon(JLabel button, String image)
{

    String path = "/ip/imag/" + image + ".png";
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
    images.put(image, icon);
    button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ip/imag/" + image + ".png")));
    return icon;
}` and it worked. Thank you for the advice, it really helped me!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you want to do, you can use this method:

```
public void setRolloverIcon(Icon rolloverIcon)
```

defined in the class JButton to configure the rollover icon.

Just create a simple class like this:

```
class HoverEffectButton extends JButton{

  HoverEffectButton(Image img1, Image img2) {
    super(new ImageIcon(img1));
    this.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
  }

}
```

Hope this will help.
And of course you can create a helper class that permits to load an image according to the image name

```
   class AssetsHelper{
   private static final String DEFAULT_ASSETS_ROOT = "assets/";
   private static final String DEFAULT_IMAGE_SUBFIX = ".png";

   public static Image loadImage(String name){
      BufferedImage img = null;
      try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(DEFAULT_ASSETS_ROOT + name + DEFAULT_IMAGE_SUBFIX));
      } catch (IOException e) {
         .... 
      }
      return img;
   }
```

}

Comment: The problem it's not setting the mouseover effect. I need to make a function that will be used like: className(b1 ,B); and do the same thing for the other labels: className(b2 ,C); and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyButton extends JButton {
    private ImageIcon normalIcon;
    private ImageIcon hoverIcon;

    public MyButton(String normalURL) {
        String hoverURL = normalURL.replaceFirst("\\.png$", "-hover.png");
        normalIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ip/imag/" +B+ ".png"); // or so
        hoverICon = ...
    }

    private void b1MouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {                           
        setIcon(hoverIcon);
    }    
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem to address the problem.

Comment: @Dukeling it would do away with the different event handlers using one, which seems the intention. Mint's answer is nicer though.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly at the top of your code add this import:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
//Then you only need to write
new ImageIcon(...);
```

Instead of:

```
new javax.swing.ImageIcon(...)
```

Already shorter :)

Then you can create a hashmap of the images preloaded where each instance of B is the key and the loaded icon is the value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I really need to create the class

Answer (score 0):

if i get u well i think you want just an image  and not evry image to chang when mouse is on it right. if that is the case what u should do is to get the position of each image in a buffer and compare it with the mouse x n y position to know wc image to change. I hope this solve your  problem